# How can I show a random image among the ones stored in the Firebase storage in FlutterFlow?

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutterflow

I have 10 pictures stored in Firebase storage.
I have a FlutterFlow project and I want to show 1 of those pictures.
The picture should randomly change anytime I refresh the page.

I know how to link Firestore with FlutterFlow and how to create an image widget.
The only thing I can't do is to link the storage with the FlutterFlow UI and link it to the random algorithm.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.